# Why importing a Svelte TS component in a Svelte TS project throws and blocks compilation?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3

If you start [the project](https://github.com/frederikhors/svelte-ts-import-ts-component) it throws a Typescript error:

`Error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`

```
> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev
> rollup -c -w

rollup v2.42.3
bundles src/main.ts → public\build\bundle.js...
[!] Error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
node_modules\svelte-ts-component\src\common\common.ts (1:0)
1: interface Utils {
   ^
2:   title: string;
3: }
Error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:5308:30)
    at Module.error (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:9717:16)
    at Module.tryParse (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:10123:25)
    at Module.setSource (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:10024:24)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18358:20)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18414:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchStaticDependencies (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18
439:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (C:\a\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18416:9)
```

**The REPO**: https://github.com/frederikhors/svelte-ts-import-ts-component

You can clone it and

`npm install`

`npm run dev`

It's a simple `sveltejs/template` project with Typescript.

In `App.svelte` I'm trying to use a Svelte TS component `Card` ([here the source code](https://github.com/frederikhors/svelte-ts-component)).

The component is imported in `package.json` like this:

`"svelte-ts-component": "frederikhors/svelte-ts-component"`

[In the component's `package.json`](https://github.com/frederikhors/svelte-ts-component/blob/516b7c3749d2c7b7b51b109efc49bdd3f0ac7f07/package.json#L8) I have this line:

`"svelte": "src/index.ts"`

because I want Svelte to compile it's source code (I don't wanna use the already compiled bundle from that component's build process).

**Information about the system:**

OS: Windows 10

Node: 14.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE

npm: 7.6.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

rollup: 2.42.3 => 2.42.3

svelte: 3.35.0 => 3.35.0

Comment: Have you tried running [`node scripts/setupTypeScript.js`](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript#Try_it_now)?

Comment: Oh yea. This is not a problem with Svelte I think. It is Rollup can't compile typescript from node_modules. A crazy thing!

Comment: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/842